# Java programming exception

Tags: java, exception

Can any one help me?  I do not understand this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at charPerLine.main(charPerLine.java:13)
```

Here's the code responsible:

```
import java.util.*;
public class charPerLine {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type any name:");
        String s=sc.next();
        int j= s.length()+1;
        for(int i=0;i<=j;i++){
            System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are accessing further than your string length. You need to post some code to let us understand why.

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to directly access the 10th character of a string which has less than 10 characters.  Something like:

```
"12345".charAt(9)
```

Remember that String indices are 0-based, hence `.charAt(9)` => 10th character.  So `"123".charAt(3)` would throw, too.

Comment: Very true, common cause is such loop `for (i = 0; i <= length; i++)` the `=` will cause that error..

Comment: Which is why we have `for (char c : "123".toCharArray()) {...}` :)

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing a character at position 9, which is outside the range of the actual string. Remember to check that it's within the range [0, length[.

Answer (score 3):

Ah. Thanks to Greg for spotting the link to the other half of this question. He is right, it isn't fair.

Your for loop goes from 0 to whatever the length of `s` is plus one.

So if s was an array:

```
['a','b','c']
```

Then it would go from 0 to 4. The indexes of that array are 0, 1 and 2. So you are trying to access two point beyond the end.

You want to **remove** this line:

```
int j= s.length()+1;
```

And change the for loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
```

Answer (score 2):

`j` is `s.length()+1` and then `i` is `<=j`. So: `s.charAt(i)` will eventually access index `length()+1`, which is 2 more than it is allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

The loop should be:

```
for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
  System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
}
```

The last character in the string has index:

`s.length() - 1`

so you need to use the guard:

`i < s.length()`

This way your loop terminates before `i` becomes `s.length()`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
s.charAt(i)
```

will throw an error, if `i` is larger or equal than `s.length()`. Try using

```
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    // ...
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

just replace the

```
int j= s.length()+1;
for(int i=0;i<=j;i++){
 ...
}
```

with

```
int j= s.length();
for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
 ...
}
```

:)