# What is wrong in in this code?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java programing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209548/java-programing-exception)

Can any one help me?  I do not understand this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at charPerLine.main(charPerLine.java:13)
```

Here's the code

```
import java.util.*;
public class charPerLine {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type any name:");
        String s=sc.next();
        int j= s.length()+1;
        for(int i=0;i<=j;i++){
            System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```